# How do I map a key to search for a pattern and replace it with newline in ex/vi?

Tags: ex-mode, original-vi

I am trying to map `q` in vi (not Vim) to find a pattern and replace it with newline:

```
Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
```

to

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
```

When I try ([Ctrl-V] and [Enter] are actual keystrokes)

```
:map q :%s/Name. /[Ctrl-V][Enter]&/g[Ctrl-V][Enter]
```

It fails, since it considers the first [Ctrl-V][Enter] itself as enter. I don't know how to make it a literal newline.

I have read [Carriage return vs newline in vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91484/carriage-return-vs-newline-in-vim) and it suggests using `\r` for newline while replacing. This seems only to work in Vim and does not work under vi.

Please help.

Comment: 1. Vi doesn't have a `:map` command so you are not using it. 2. `q` is a very useful operator, you should probably reconsider mapping it.

Comment: @romainl yes, it does. See the part I quoted from http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/viin/paper-6.html#section42.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a bit convoluted, but, try:

```
:map q :%s/Name. /\^V^V^M&/g^M
```

Each `^x` is produced by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>*x*</kbd>, so the actual sequence here is:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for the first `^V`,
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for the second `^V`,
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the first `^M`.
4. And again for the last `^M`.

From [`man ex`](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/ex.html):

> Lines may be split by substituting new-line characters into them. The
>   newline in repl must be escaped by preceding it with a '\'. Other
>   metacharacters available in pat and repl are described below.

And from [*An Introduction to Display Editing with Vi*](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/viin/paper-6.html#section42):

> You can use the map command from *vi* (typically in your *EXINIT*)
>   with a command of the form:
>
> ```
> :map lhs rhsCR
> ```
>
> mapping *lhs* into *rhs*. There are restrictions: lhs should be one
>   keystroke (either 1 character or one function key) since it must be
>   entered within one second (unless *notimeout* is set, in which case
>   you can type it as slowly as you wish, and *vi* will wait for you to
>   finish it before it echoes anything). The *lhs* can be no longer than
>   10 characters, the *rhs* no longer than 100. To get a space, tab or
>   newline into *lhs* or *rhs* you should escape them with a **^V**. (It
>   may be necessary to double the **^V** if the map command is given
>   inside *vi*, rather than in *ex*.) Spaces and tabs inside the *rhs*
>   need not be escaped.

So:

1. We need to prefix the newline given to `:s` with a `\`.
2. If we were typing the command in `vi`, then we'd press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to get the newline in the command. That means we have to make the mapping so that it would be as if we had pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.
3. We need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> just to get one `^V` to the command. But we need two, so that it would be as if we'd typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

The reduction would be like this:

1. `^V^V^V^V^V^M` typed
2. Which the `map` command will receive as `^V^V^M`
3. Which will be interpreted while executing the map as `^V^M`
4. To get a literal `^M`.

After all that, the output still won't be what you wanted:

```
​
Name1
Name2
Name3 Name4
```

Comment: Nice +1! To get the output desired by @Banavara, in the replacement part, maybe you could invert the order of the newline and the backreference to the whole pattern `&`:  `:map q :%s/Name. /&\^V^V^M/g^M`

Comment: WOW...! Fantastic muru. I had to read 2/3 times to understand that. It works like charm. for the last part, * operator matching none or more occurance can be used as `:map q :%s/Name. */\^V^V^M&/g^M` (but it still inserts a newline at the top. I have another question regarding this, will post it as a different question. (The answer was so good, I created an account to comment! Thank you muru)

Comment: @Banavara thanks. But see user9433424's comment above, I'd say that's correct.

Comment: Thank you @user9433424, your solution works just as I specified. The reason for inserting newline before Name is that there are some other details after Name field and I wanted all records to be broken Name field, so that all details are on their own line.